# PHP 5.2.17 deb repo

Tags: php, ubuntu, debian, repository

So I have this really old website that will only work on 5.2.x and the cost of migration to 7.x is just ridiculous for us as a company.
I have tried getting 5.2.17 to work alongside 7.x on the Ubuntu Server 16.04 but because it was a source based install, I’m struggling in getting modules to work on the 5.2.x enabled website. It come to a point where it would be just easier to install a separate very old Linux distro and just run it off of it with 5.2 onboard installed and configured from a repo.
So my question is, does anyone would be able to help with acquiring 5.2.17 Debian repository? The website is used internally only and just so we can have access to the database that’s behind it.

Thanks!

Comment: You could use something like a docker image.

Comment: It will probably make you life a lot easier if you can use a higher version like 5.6. That is still supported, easy to find and should not break too much.

Comment: @jeroen that’s actually great idea, thanks! Do you know of any apps that can scan the code in search of obsolete functions?

Comment: Your IDE? Using phpstorm for example that should be possible.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.php I'd read back through the incompatible migration notes to 5.2 if that's the way you go.

Comment: @jeroen I just use notepad++, I’m no dev, the company that employs me as an IT Manager recently acquired another company and it’s their system I’m struggling with because it’s so old. I’ll give phpstorm a go, thank you :)

Comment: @Progrock thanks, that’s very useful!